# Routing Directs to a blank page

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a project that I'm working on using AngularJS and Angular-route for a class.  I'm using as a template the structure of an assignment from the class, but for some reason I can't get the project page to display.

I have the following file structure:

[image]

config.js:

```
/**
 * Created by Anthony on 8/4/2017.
 */
(function () {
    angular
        .module("SpotifyReviews")
        .config(Config);
    function Config($routeProvider) {
        console.log("hello from config");
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "views/templates/search.view.client.html",
                controller: "SearchController",
                controllerAs: "model"
            })

    }
});
```

app.js:

```
/**
 * Created by Anthony on 8/4/2017.
 */
(function () {
    angular
        .module("SpotifyReviews", ["ngRoute"]);
})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="SpotifyReviews">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Project Home Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js  "></script>
    <script src="views/controllers/search.controller.client.js"></script>
    <script src="services/search.service.client.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div ng-view class="ng-scope">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

search.controller.client.js:

```
/**
 * Created by Anthony on 7/24/2017.
 */
(function () {
    angular
        .module("SpotifyReviews")
        .controller("SearchController", SearchController);

    function SearchController($location, $routeParams, SearchService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.albums = [];

        vm.albumSearch = albumSearch;


        function init() {
            vm.queryString = "";
            console.log("hello");
        }

        init();

        function albumSeach() {
            SearchService.searchAlbum(vm.queryString)
                .then(vm.albums = response.data);
        }


    }

})();
```

search.service.client.js:

```
/**
 * Created by Anthony on 7/23/2017.
 */

(function () {
    angular
        .module("SpotifyReviews")
        .factory("SearchService", SearchService);
    function SearchService($http) {

        var api = {
            "searchAlbum": searchAlbum
        };
        return api;

        function searchAlbum(queryString) {



        }


    }
})();
```

I'm following, as far as I can tell, the exact same structure as I have in public/assignment, but I cannot for the life of me get it to display.  Navigating to localhost:3000/assignment automatically redirects to localhost:3000/assignment/#!/, but localhost:3000/project and localhost:3000/#!/ both just show a blank screen.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you *sure* you aren't seeing any errors in the console?  It appears like you are using a **very old** version of angular-route, which won't work.  You **must** use the exact same version of angular-route as version of angular, in this case `1.6.4`.  Angular-route `1.2.0rc1` will not work with angular `1.6.4`.

Comment: @Claies I switched to 1.6.4 for both and its still not working.

Absolutely nothing in the console: http://i.imgur.com/WbpqisJ.png

Comment: your config.js is an IIFE but it's never executed.  add `()` at the end of the IIFE for the function to actually fire and add the routes.